# I am not getting any output for my python file

Tags: python

```
def function():
    l = input("Enter the length of rectangle: ")
    b = input("Enter the breadth of rectangle: ")
    ask = input("Do you want to calculate area or perimeter?(a/p): ")
    if ask == a or A:
        area = l*b
        print("Area of a rectangle with length of",l,"and breadth of",b,"is",area)

    elif ask == p or P:
        peri = 2*(l+b)
        print("Perimeter of a rectangle with length of",l,"and breadth of",b,"is",peri)

else:
    print("ERROR 404 , try again.")

    function()
```

I am not able to get any output for the following code upon running this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get output that says "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on line 13, pointing to the incorrectly indented `else:` statement?

Comment: Also, [`if x == a or b` is (almost) always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al). You probably want to use `if x == a or x == b` or `if x in {a, b}`.

Comment: `a`, `A`, `p` and `P` are treated like variables and are not defined. You probably meant `"a", "A", ...`. Also `l` and `b` are strings, so multiplication will not work for them.

Comment: I suspect your real code doesn't have the improperly indented `else:`, but has the indented call to `function()`. Like that you are simply defining a function and never calling it. That would explain the lack of output.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

You are comparing ask to variables a, A, p, and P that don't exist. Instead, you should be comparing to the string literals 'a', 'A', 'p', and 'P'.

The values l and b that you receive from the input() function are strings. You need to convert them to integers or floats before performing arithmetic operations.

The indentation of the function() call at the end of the code is incorrect. It should not be indented.

The else: block is mispositioned. You should probably align it with the if and elif blocks.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
def function():
    l = float(input("Enter the length of rectangle: "))  # converting to float
    b = float(input("Enter the breadth of rectangle: "))  # converting to float
    ask = input("Do you want to calculate area or perimeter?(a/p): ")
    
    if ask == 'a' or ask == 'A':
        area = l * b
        print("Area of a rectangle with length of", l, "and breadth of", b, "is", area)

    elif ask == 'p' or ask == 'P':
        peri = 2 * (l + b)
        print("Perimeter of a rectangle with length of", l, "and breadth of", b, "is", peri)

    else:
        print("ERROR 404 , try again.")
        function()

function()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here. First of all, when you check to see when the player typed in `a` or `p`, they should be in quotation marks to show that they are strings and not variable names: `"a" or "A"`.

Second of all, you need to cast the length and breadth inputs to integers so that they can be operated on. Do this with `l = int(input("Enter the length of the rectangle: "))`. Don't do this with `ask` though because you want that to be a string!

The entire `else` block should also be indented 4 spaces or a tab so that it is on the same indentation level as the `if` and `elif`.
Also, instead of using `if ask == "a" or "A"` you can do `if ask.lower() == "a"` which first converts all characters to lowercase so the `if` statement looks prettier.